# Convert Map to Bundle in android

Tags: android, firebase, bundle, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there an easy way to convert a Map to a Bundle in android without explicit iteration?

**Why?**

Firebase returns a Map for Notification `getData()`. I need to pass the data to an intent. Formerly GCM gave me a bundle, so I didn't need to worry about this.

Comment: "Is there an easy way to convert a Map to a Bundle in android without explicit iteration?" -- note that a `Map` does not necessarily equate to a `Bundle`. A `Map` can have keys that are not strings. A `Map` can have values that are not one of the supported data types.

Comment: Yes, but in my case they are all primitives and String

Comment: You could serialize it.

Comment: The RemoteMessage object is parcelable, you could just send that directly in the intent

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I guess a good old fashioned for loop is the easiest way:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : getData().entrySet()) {
        bundle.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: this will probably throw an exception because first parameter "google_sent_time" has a Long type and you are using `putString`. you better use the intent to handle type variation for you and use `intent.putExtra(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())` so different data types dont make problem for you.

Comment: @AmirZiarati I don't think that is true anymore, `RemoteMessage#getData()` now returns a `Map<String, String>` excluding a bunch of the internal values.

Answer (score 29):

Neat Kotlin solution using spread operator will look like that:

```
fun Map<String, Any?>.toBundle(): Bundle = bundleOf(*this.toList().toTypedArray())
```

Comment: Worth noting is that the spread operator is not the best for performance and the above solution will generate a performance warning in some static analysis tools like for example Detekt:
https://detekt.github.io/detekt/performance.html#spreadoperator

Comment: worth mentioning that this won't create nested bundles for nested maps, in case you're using something like FIrebase Analytics that requires that

Answer (score 16):

Came across this same issue with firebase messaging and created a kotlin extension function for it. The [gist is here](https://gist.github.com/bulwinkel/60f2d06314c0d43225204c00251f1f48), code below. Although I am using this method there are some caveats:

- it doesn't cover all of the types that can be put into a bundle
- it is still under development and hasn't been fully tested

With this in mind, please use it as a guide not a definitive solution. I will keep the gist up to date as it evolves.

```
import android.os.Bundle 
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.Parcelable
import java.io.Serializable

fun <V> Map<String, V>.toBundle(bundle: Bundle = Bundle()): Bundle = bundle.apply {
  forEach {
    val k = it.key
    val v = it.value
    when (v) {
      is IBinder -> putBinder(k, v)
      is Bundle -> putBundle(k, v)
      is Byte -> putByte(k, v)
      is ByteArray -> putByteArray(k, v)
      is Char -> putChar(k, v)
      is CharArray -> putCharArray(k, v)
      is CharSequence -> putCharSequence(k, v)
      is Float -> putFloat(k, v)
      is FloatArray -> putFloatArray(k, v)
      is Parcelable -> putParcelable(k, v)
      is Serializable -> putSerializable(k, v)
      is Short -> putShort(k, v)
      is ShortArray -> putShortArray(k, v)

//      is Size -> putSize(k, v) //api 21
//      is SizeF -> putSizeF(k, v) //api 21

      else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("$v is of a type that is not currently supported")
//      is Array<*> -> TODO()
//      is List<*> -> TODO()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: never heard of kotlin before today; interesting find

Answer (score 12):

Nowadays you can use `fun bundleOf(vararg pairs: Pair<String, Any?>)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)`to generate a `Parcel` that could be similarly useful, since it's a parent class of `Bundle`, and it's handily built into the Firebase framework as part of the `RemoteMessage` class. Documentation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel,%20int)).

Comment: `Parcel` is a superclass of `Bundle`, so while it can be similarly useful, they can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: Yep, I did mention that it's the parent class of it.

Comment: Your answer maybe is better, but the lack of explanation or example is making it worst.

Answer (score 1):

here is how I did it in Kotlin

```
val bundle = Bundle()

for (entry in data.entries)
    bundle.putString(entry.key, entry.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can build a function extension to convert Map to Bundle without explicit iteration like so:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val payload = remoteMessage.data.toBundle()
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification payload: $payload")
        // ...
}
```

where ***toBundle()*** is defined like so:

```
inline fun <reified T> Map<String, T>.toBundle(): Bundle = bundleOf(*toList<String, T?>().toTypedArray())
```

or again:

```
inline fun <reified T> Map<String, T>.toBundle(): Bundle = bundleOf(*map { it.key to it.value }.toTypedArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

In a kotlin way:

```
private fun Map<String, Any>.toBundle(): Bundle {
    val pairs = this.map { entry ->
        Pair(entry.key, entry.value)
    }.toTypedArray()
    return bundleOf(*pairs)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extention method in Kotlin:

```
fun Map<String, Any>.toBundle() = bundleOf(*toList().toTypedArray())
```

Answer (score -1):

For future reference

> Convert Map to String

```
  fun Map<String, String>.convertExtraMapToString(): String? {
    return keys.stream()
        .map { key: String -> "$key=" + this[key] }.collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"))
}
```

> Convert String to Map then to Bundle

```
fun String.convertExtraMapToBundle(): Bundle {
    return Arrays.stream(split(",".toRegex()).toTypedArray())
        .map { entry: String -> entry.split("=".toRegex()).toTypedArray() }
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            { entry: Array<String> -> entry[0] }) { entry: Array<String> -> entry[1] }).let {
            bundleOf(*it.toList().toTypedArray())
        }
}
```

Answer (score -11):

```
 private ArrayList<Bundle> convertMapToBundleList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mapList)
```