# Parcel is a superclass of Bundle?

Tags: android

Basically, I want to convert the [ArrayMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html) of RemoteMessage.data into a Bundle. In this question ([Convert Map to Bundle in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469241/convert-map-to-bundle-in-android)), [an answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39361800/455796) `writeToParcel` should be useful as `Parcel` is a parent class of `Bundle`.

But when I looked it up, Bundle extends BaseBundle, which extends Object. What do they mean parent? Can I use `writeToParcel` to write the data of an ArrayMap to a Bundle?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html

Comment: No, the type of `data` is `ArrayMap`. I was trying to link the documentation page to that word, but my damn cheap Internet was disconnected and just got back.

Comment: Try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909061/passing-object-array-list-between-fragments-in-android-development/43910817#43910817. If this didn't work then I think you have to go with writeToParcel

Comment: It is not ArrayList but `ArrayMap` and I was trying to pass a bundle to `writeToParcel`, which did not work. I experimented a little, and the following code seemed to compile (not tested yet).

    var p = Parcel.obtain();
   remoteMessage.writeToParcel(p, 0);
   var b = Bundle();
   b.putParcelable("data", b)