# How to send MutableMap from activity to another with intent

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablemap

I have mutable Map as `private var optionsList: MutableMap<String, List<String>> = mutableMapOf()` and i need to send it to another activity , i used this :

```
        val optionsIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, OptionsActivity::class.java)
        optionsIntent.putExtra(
            "optionsLi",optionsList)
        startActivity(optionsIntent)
```

And it gives me an error in `putExtra`, but I can't find anything that is like putMap or something to use.

Comment: [Convert Map to Bundle in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37470356/3290339)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
private var optionsList: HashMap<String, List<String>> = hashMapOf()
```

Instead of

```
private var optionsList: MutableMap<String, List<String>> = mutableMapOf()
```

**As HashMap implements the Serializable interface, which makes it easy to add it to an intent**

Comment: @Onik, In Kotlin `HashMap<K, V>` is typealias which actually point to `java.util.HashMap<K, V>`. Here is the implementation: `public actual typealias HashMap<K, V> = java.util.HashMap<K, V>`

Comment: Actually `LinkedHashMap<K, V> extends MutableMap<K, V>`